# Python: regex pattern to extract substring after prefix when no suffix is present

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract substring from every item of a list. The substring has to be placed after `'opt_'` prefix and no `'_join'` suffix can be present in a string.

My input:

```
my_opts = [
    'opt_tw',
    'opt_ls_join',
    'opt_ac_join',
    'opt_pan_join',
    'opt_full_led',
]
```

Desired output:

```
['tw', 'full_led']
```

What I have tried:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'opt_?(.*)[^_join]'
>>> print([
...     re.search(pattern, opt).group(1)
...     for opt in my_opts
...     if re.match(pattern, opt)
... ])
['t', 'l', 'a', 'p', 'full_le']
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: If you must use regex, maybe use `^opt_(.*)(?<!_join)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match `_opt` and optionally match until the last occurrence of `_`.

Then assert not `join` at the end of the string, and capture the rest in group 1.

```
opt_((?:.*_)?(?!join$)[^\r\n_]+)$
```

- `opt_` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:.*_)?` Optionally match until the last occurrence of `_`
  - `(?!join$)` Negative lookahead, assert not join at the end of the string
  - `[^\r\n_]+` Match 1+ times any char except `_` (or newlines)
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[REgex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCqrUo/1)

```
import re

my_opts = [
    'opt_tw',
    'opt_ls_join',
    'opt_ac_join',
    'opt_pan_join',
    'opt_full_led',
]

pattern = r"opt_((?:.*_)?(?!join$)[^\r\n_]+)$"
for s in my_opts:
    match = re.match(pattern, s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
tw
full_led
```

If the string should not contain `_join` you can use a negative lookahead

```
^opt_(?!.*_join)(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C8pHp7/1)

Comment: @MustafaAydın It should be re.match, I used re.search which will start at the beginning at the string. I have updated it.

Comment: I see, then I undeleted my answer because I thought we need to match `opt_` anywhere... (but if that's not the case, I'll delete again, OP might need to clarify `:)`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.startswith`](http://%5B%27tw%27,%20%27full_led%27%5D) and [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) for the conditions and string slicing for the capturing group:

```
out = [opt[4:]
       for opt in my_opts
       if opt.startswith("opt_") and not opt.endswith("_join")]
```

where 4 is equal to the length of `"opt_"` and helps get substring after that,

to get

```
>>> out
["tw", "full_led"]
```

Comment: Just a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lt68Kr) showing it works well.